# Expected sum of n-sided dices

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two questions regarding expected sums:

$a)$ Three dice have $6, 12 ,4$ sides respectively. What is the expected sum?

$b)$ What is the expected sum of $6$ dice, each $8$ sided?

--

Is the only method here direct calculations?

I know that

$$E[R] = \sum_{i=0}^nR_i*P_i$$ where $R_i, P_i$ are the return and probability in the ith scenario.

I could apply the formula directly, but it seems it would involve a very long calculation.
I'm wondering if there is a smarter approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Expectation is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Assume that the dice throws are fair  and that the $k$ faces are $\{1,\dotsc, k\}$. Then the outcome of the $k$-sided die $X_k$ follows a discrete uniform distribution with the well-known expectation
$$E[X_k] = \frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{1+k}{2}.$$

Then for a) call the sum $S = X_4+X_6+X_{12}$, calculate $E[S]$.

How does it work for b)? (Slightly different logic/notation.)
Addendum: Since each random variable is not equal, but equal in distribution, then call them $X_8^{(1)}, X_8^{(2)},\dotsc, X_8^{(6)}$ and proceed as in a).

Comment: You don't even have to assume independence. Expectation is linear regardless.

Comment: Oh yeah, just being careful I guess. Haha.

Comment: I often like to err on the side of caution as well.

Comment: @Max for a) what you suggest is that I can calculate each dice's expected value of individually and add, since expectations are linear right? For b), could I not use the same idea and simply add the expected sum $X_8$ $6$ times?

Comment: a) is fine. b) Not quite. The idea is right, but calling each $X_8$ suggests that they all have the same value, or that they are the same random variable. Instead, it's best to write something like $Y_1,\dotsc, Y_6$, where each $Y_i$ follows a discrete uniform distribution on $[1, \dotsc, 8]$. It's a subtle, but important distinction. I suppose I could have written my notation differently from the beginning, and called the first three $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$, or $X,Y, Z$ where each follows a different uniform distribution.

Comment: @user282639 Oh, I remember what I had in mind: calling them $X_8^{(1)}, X_8^{(2)},\dotsc, X_8^{(6)}.$ This would distinguish them.

Comment: @Max Ah! I see what you're saying now. Cheers!